# How do I make it so that if XPATH doesn't see an element on a website, it skips that line and moves on to the next line?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How do I make it so that if XPATH doesn't see the element on the page, it skips the element and moves on to the next line? My code is:

```
1. driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[@alt = "Black"]').click()
```

and then if it doesn't find the 1st element, it skips and tries to find:

```
2. driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input').click()
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with "if ___ is displayed, click, else if ____ click", although I'm not sure how to format that.

Comment: find_elements_by_xpath will return a list you can check size of in order to use it in an if instead of try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try and catch block and catch ElementNotFoundException exception
Java:

```
try{
 //your code to find element
}
catch(ElementNotFoundException)
{
  //print element not found
}
// find another element and perform action
```

Reference-https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Python:

```
 try:
  //your code
 except ElementNotFoundException:
   print("ELEMENT NOT fOUND")
```

Comment: In the end, I used a try, except, finally block, meaning that even if the info inside "try" is wrong, the info inside the "finally" block will be executed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In xpath you can get the union of two node-sets

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//img[@alt = "Black"]|//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input').click()
```

Comment: But how would I make it so that even if xpath doesn't find '//img[@alt = "Black"]' then it still clicks '//*[@id="add-remove-buttons"]/input' ?

Comment: That's what the `|` is for. It collects everything on both sides. For example, after opening stackoverflow.com, I used `//tr|//div`. There aren't any tr's in the page so I got the first div.